# Where are the mystics?

Tags: continuity, dark-crystal, dark-crystal-age-of-resistance

I looked up Age of Resistance last night, and some of what I saw kind of contradicts the original movie. Far as I can tell there was nothing about the crystal breaking, Aughra used to watch over the crystal until the Skeksis distracted her with the orrery and the Gelfling are working for the Skeksis. But the strangest part is they don't mention anything about the Mystics - aren't they and the Skeksis splinters from another race (they were in the movie)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243599/where-are-the-mystics

Answer (score 3):

The mystics appear toward the end of the season.

> I think they are said to live in hiding, or at least be reclusive. The connection with the Skeksis does get established as you describe.